# Как установить tensorflow 1.14?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, tensorflow

У меня такая же проблема https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40869
В ответе пользователь с никнеймом shenyubin1990 ответил, что ему помогло понижение версии tensorflow с 2.2 до 1.14. При попытке установить tensorflow 1.14 вылазит ошибка [image: ошибка]
Как понизить версию или как установить tensorflow 1.14?
Система: win 10, tensorflow 2.2.0, python 3.8.5

Comment: Возможно, для более старой версии TF нужно использовать не `pip3`, а `pip`?

Comment: Не помогает. Выходит похожая ошибка: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 1.14 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for 1.14

Comment: Сдаётся мне Python у вас слишком новый, TF за ним не поспевает

Comment: Установил python 3.6.8 и проблема исчезла. Спасибо CrazyElf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установил python 3.6.8 и проблема исчезла. Спасибо CrazyElf